KUKA robot electric motor type
I am creating a theoretical study on the operating principles, structure and control of KUKA robot electric motors. However, I can't find any suitable information that lists what smart motors are in the KUKA robots. Maybe someone can help and provide a possible place to find such information?
Find information about the motors in the wheels, they are brushless, 8-pole permanently excited synchronous machines.

possible place to find such information ... the manufacturer

I have communicated, but they point to the KUKA expert page so I can look for information there, but only servo motors are written about the motors. Noting special.

What did they say when you told them that only servo information was available on the expert page? Maybe raise the issue with them, it seems to be the best course of action... unless someone has taken a KUKA robot apart to see what is actually in it (assuming that the labels haven't been taken off).
